# vuejs - how to pass data to webpacked root instance

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I have an application where I'm using `Single File Components` for showing data in a table. The data is queried based on a `search` string and columns that I want to include in the results (the data is fetched by basically an ajax request).

My goal is to create a reusable component so that I can pass the query text and the column names to the component. Normally I could use `props` and `slots` for this, but since I'm using `Single File Components` I have no idea how to pass data to the component.

The "`public`" interface to the `Single File Component` looks as follows:

```
<!-- index.hmtl -->
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="./build/webpackedComponent.js"></script>
```

---

```
// main.js / Component entry point
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/app.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Inside `App` I need the data for the ajax request. An idea I had was to import a `json` file in the main entry point of the component, but then I would have to repack the component everytime I change the json, and for multiple uses of the component, I need to pack them each time for every instance that uses different data...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your `webpack.base.conf.js` file (in my project it is located inside the `build` folder) or the equivalent configuration file, then add `library: 'myLibrary'` to the output object.

(should end up with something like this:)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: ['./src/main.js']
  },
  output: {
    library: 'myLibrary',
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  .
  .
  .
```

---

then in main.js, you can export Vue like this:

```
// main.js / Component entry point
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './components/app.vue'

export { Vue, App };
```

And now in the global scope you can do this:

```
new myLibrary.Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value1: 12,
    value2: 14
  },
  components: { App: myLibrary.App },
  template: '<App :prop1="value1", :prop2="value2"></App>'
});
```

That is, whatever you export in main.js will be accessible to the global scope via the name of the library you provided in your webpack config file... in this case, `myLibrary`.

Comment: This doesn't really help, because main.js is packed as well. So for every change of `data` I would have to repack the SFCs. What I'm looking for is someway of exposing the single file components to the global scope, so I can use them in a script tag via a new `Vue` instance, that uses those components.

Comment: @Johannes But why can't you supply `data` with the result of the Ajax call that you can make in main.js? Or use computed properties instead of `data` altogether?

Comment: Because the ajax requests requires some user input / configuration, so that the correct query is sent. I need to be able to configure/pass this input to the webpacked component, from a global scope.

Comment: @Johannes OK now I have a better understanding of your problem. What if you save the results of the ajax request in, say, `window.ajax_results`, then watch for changes in this variable inside your `App` component?

Comment: Another solution would be to move your Ajax code altogether inside `App` which makes perfect sense if you are using vuejs as the main tool for your app and not just as a tool to display the results of this particular scenario.

Comment: Saving to the results to `window` works. I was hoping for a cleaner way though. Namespace polution is something I want to avoid. And for the second solution: I can't move the ajax code inside the `App` component, because the ajax code has to be configured (manually). If I were to move it inside, I would have to repack as soon as I change the configuration.

Comment: @Johannes: I have now updated the answer based on what I learned in this discussion to a new one that hopefully is the kind of answer you wanted to get in the first place. Please don't forget to approve/rate the answer if desired. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! That's the kind of solution I was aiming for. Sadly, this doesn't work yet though. `myLibrary...` replaces the `div`, but it doesn't use the imported `App` from `./components/app.vue` to render the template. Instead, this is what's in the DOM now: `<app prop1="12" prop2="14"></app>` I guess I have to register `App` in `Vue` in the main entry point, right?

Comment: Yes that's right. Sorry about that. I will modify the answer right away.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for your help! Btw, `myLibrary.App` does not working. Either assigning it to a variable or using `App: myLibrary.App` does work though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132199/discussion-between-rashad-saleh-and-johannes).